# pass parameters inside dataframe.groupby(level).agg

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to calculate the std on a dataframe after grouping.

```
df2 = df.groupby(level='Index').agg(np.std).dropna(how='all')
```

Everything fine, but I don't know how to pass the parameter `ddof=1` to `np.std`

I would like to do this inside a function where I pass the operation to do...

```
operation = ['mean','std']
for i in range(0,len(operation)):
    df2 = df.groupby(level='Index').agg(operation[i]).dropna(how='all')
    ....
```

is it possible to replace `'mean'` and `'std'` with `np.mean` and `np.std` with ddof=1?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

```
In [298]: df
Out[298]:
     val
idx
0      0
2      2
4      0
1      2
3      0
0      2
0      0
0      0
3      4
2      2

In [299]: def std(x):
     ...:     return np.std(x, ddof=1)
     ...:

In [300]: df.groupby(level=0)['val'].agg(['mean', std]).dropna(how='all')
Out[300]:
     mean       std
idx
0     0.5  1.000000
1     2.0       NaN
2     2.0  0.000000
3     2.0  2.828427
4     0.0       NaN
```

---

Try this:

```
df2 = df.groupby(level='Index').std(ddof=1).dropna(how='all')
```

or

```
df2 = df.groupby(level='Index').agg(lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=1)).dropna(how='all')
```

or simply

```
df2 = df.groupby(level='Index').agg(np.std, ddof=1).dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: Hi THanks! this answer my question, but actually it was a bit more complex. Sorry if I didnt specify before... I edited my question..

Comment: @gabboshow, i don't understand updated question - you are overwriting `df2` in each iteration - does it make sense? It would be better/easier if you would provide a sample data set and your desired data set

Comment: yes you are right, but it is just an example...later I do other operations with df2

Comment: @gabboshow, do you want to apply both operations (mean, std) or just some of them?

Comment: I want to apply both (together with other statistics)